# RAML inside MULE (3.x) anypoint studio is giving a null payload

Tags: rest, mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, raml

RAML inside MULE (3.x) anypoint studio is giving a null payload due to http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd is not found. Why was it removed? Any alternatives?

Comment: Could you add a bit more details? What is the exact error in the logs? When does it occur? That XSD should be required on start up and is required at the mule config file level.

Comment: The project ran successfully and I could able to see the RAML browser. But when I submit a request through RAML it is getiing a NULL payload

Comment: The XSD thing is not your problem, you should check the flow logic handling that request you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

The XSDs needed are included in the modules or connectors. If Mule tries to reach an XSD from the Internet usually is because it wasn't correctly packaged. If this is a Mule version earlier than 3.8 it is likely that the APIKit module was not included in the deployable application. For Maven builds, the dependency has to be added to pom, even if you see APIKit in Studio.

Comment: I don't see a issue in build. The build is successful and the RAML browser is loaded successfully on deployment

Comment: I don't see the xsd error but it is my suspect that it might what cause the issue. I can able to submit the request from my RAML file and it can not be forwarded to the concern API. When i was looking at the xml i checked the xsd and found that it is missing. So I thought it was the issue

Comment: Then the description is a bit misleading. You should clarify what is an actual symptom and what is a theory. I would expect a missing schema would cause an error, not a null response. You should share the configurations, RAML, logs to understand better the issue. And probably add more logging to see when the value changes.